# how to cast an int array to a byte array in C

Tags: c, arrays, byte

hey i would like to know how you could cast an Int array in C to an byte array and what would be the declaration method. I would appreciate if it is simpler and no use of pointers. thanks for the comments

ex: int addr[500] to byte[]

Plus I would also want the ending byte array to have the same array name.

Comment: An integer is 32 bits, where as a byte is 8 bits. Are you looking to have your byte array 4 times the size of the integer array, and store each integer over 4 bytes?

Comment: you want to access all bytes of each int, or only the low byte of each int?

Comment: Int is 4 or 8 bytes long (by definition at lest 2 I think)... How do you want it to convert to 1B type? To `char[2000]` or what? Do you know the difference between little and big endians?

Comment: What do you mean by "cast"?  Do you want an array containing the same values in each position?  Or do you want an array containing the same data but with a different interpretation?

Comment: as @joshhendo described above, I would like to store each integer in 4 byte. so I want to know how to do that. thanks

Answer (score 15):

**If** you are trying to **reinterpret** the memory behind the int array as an array of bytes, and only then:

```
int ints[500];
char *bytes = (char *) ints;
```

You **cannot** do this without resorting to pointer casting, as declaring a `[]` array implies allocation on stack, and cannot be used for reinterpretation of existing memory.

Obviously, you need to know what you are doing. For each `int` there will be (typically, depending on platform etc.) 4 `char`s, so your new array would have `500*4` elements. Check out what the output of:

```
printf("char size: %d, int size: %d", sizeof(char), sizeof(int));
```

tells you to make sure.

**If** you are trying to interpret each `int` as a `char`, i.e. to get the same number of `char`s, as there were `int`s, then you **cannot** do this without a loop and manual conversion (to a new memory locaton, normally).

Comment: It should be made very clear though, this does not convert your ints to chars in any way, it just tricks the compiler to use the memory you allocated for ints for bytes instead.

Comment: It is worth noting that this is one of the very few pointer casts that is guaranteed to be safe by the C standard.

Comment: @DietrichEpp what does "safe" exactly mean?

Comment: @Vyktor I think it's safe because the alignment requirements of `char` are less strict than those of `int`

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson Edited to make that (hopefully) very clear, thanks.

Comment: is the *bytes the array or just an element of the array?

Comment: I strongly suggest to read introductory material to pointers and memory allocation in C, this cannot be answered simply, at the same time making it clear for you.

`char *bytes` is the declaration;

`*bytes` is the first element of the `bytes` array, same as `bytes[0]`;

`bytes[i]` is the byte at index `i` (generally, "`i+1`th" element).

Comment: Alignment is just a small part of the issue. The other part is aliasing. Only `char` types are allowed to alias other types in C.

Comment: @Vyktor: The C standard guarantees that if you have some `T *ptr`, then you can cast to `(unsigned char *) ptr` and read the values byte by byte.  The C standard says that the behavior is undefined for *every other type* besides `unsigned char`.  For example, no strictly conforming program can execute `*(unsigned short *) ptr`, but a strictly conforming program may perform `*(unsigned char *) ptr`.  It's also guaranteed that you can, e.g., copy an object to an `unsigned char` array and back with `memcpy` without corrupting it.  See n1256 6.2.6.1.

Answer (score 4):

You can use a union.

```
union {
  int ints[500];
  char bytes[0];
} addr;
```

Comment: This is a great answer--its actually the only answer that meets the OPs request of "no pointers." Of course, if they were trying to get around pointers because they don't understand them, a union might not be any better...

Comment: I think using union for type casting is UB.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to

1. reinterpret the memory behind the `int` array as bytes,
2. want to avoid pointers *syntactically* --for whatever reason--, and
3. making a copy of the `int` array is acceptable,

then you could create a new `char` array and copy the `int` array with `memcpy`:

```
int ints[500];
char bytes[500 * 4];
memcpy(bytes, ints, 500 * 4);
```

This is about the same as the first snippet from my original answer, with the difference that the `bytes` contain a *copy* of the `ints` (i.e. modifying one doesn't influence the other). Usual caveats about `int` size and avoiding magic constants/refactoring code apply.

Answer (score 0):

It might be easier to use pointers but without pointers, try the following:

```
    #include <stdio.h>

    typedef unsigned char byte;

    void main() {
            int addr_size = 500;
            int addr[ addr_size ];
            byte bytes[ addr_size * 4 ];

            int i;
            for( i = 0; i < addr_size; i++ ) {
                    bytes[ i ] = (byte)( addr[ i ] >> 24);
                    bytes[ i + 1 ] = (byte)( addr[ i ] >> 16);
                    bytes[ i + 2 ] = (byte)( addr[ i ] >> 8);
                    bytes[ i + 3 ] = (byte)addr[ i ];
            }
    }
```

Comment: I'm afraid the shifts will raise more questions for the OP than answers they may give...

Comment: I'm afraid I don't have an answer to his constraints :) what would you suggest without pointers?

Comment: "Cannot do" ;-) At least not without writing unnecessarily complicated code and raising even more questions. Pointers are there for a damn-very-good reason in C, and writing C without them is like riding a bike without using legs and possibly one hand. C++ is a different story though.

Comment: What's unnecessary in my code? I don't think you can do better than that if you're making two copies of the same array. What you mentioned below just points to the same memory. And the shifting are still using pointers :D

Comment: I'm not criticizing your code -- moreover, assuming the no-pointers constraint, it's probably *the* solution. I'm referring to a more general situation in real world, where such a constraint leads to unnecessary code. I'm criticizing the constraint. No sane reviewer would prefer your code over mine, because no sane person would put *that* constraint in place. (Again, I'm not really comparing "your code" vs. "my code" here, that's not the point :-) )

Comment: Actually... Look at my new answer xD

Comment: where is the casting? most of those basic questions come from school homework.