# pick pair of bit (0b11) in memory array

Tags: c, count, bit

my embedded system has 128KB memory array structure for specific purpose

and each 2bit represents 4state( state 0 ,state 1, state 2, state 3)

I'd like to count total state 3 (0b11) in memory array

for example 0xFF001234 = 1111 1111 0000 0000 0001 0010 0011 0100

It counts 5 (0b11)

I searched algorithm but it only counts single bit
- https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/count-set-bits-in-an-integer/

I hope to avoid greedy algorithm like compare 0b11 every 2bit

anyone has good idea?

ps : I'm using LEON3 Sparc V8 32bit processor, using C language

Comment: What programming language are you using and how do you access the memory?

Comment: Sorry, I am using C language

Comment: And what is the type if your "*memory array structure*"?

Comment: it is just array of 4byte memory

Comment: The processor really accesses the memory 4 bits per 4 bits ? Sounds surprising.

Comment: Writing an effective algorithm for this is all about how big chunks your CPU can munch in a single instruction. It will look wildly different on a 32 bit CPU and a 8 bit CPU. Also, it depends on if you can utilize data cache or not. Attempting to design an effective algorithm for this without a specific target in mind is quackery. So what is your target here?

Comment: I am sorry for replying late. I am using LEON3 sparc v8

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have an array `uint32_t states[]` where each `state[i]` represents 16 states?

To count the number of `0b11` states in the variable `uint32_t s` you can use the following approach:

First, pre-process `s` such that every state `0b11` leads to exactly one `1` bit and all other states lead to `0` bits. Then count the numbers of `1` bits.

## Pre-Processing

Split `s` into the left bits `l` and right bits `r` of each state.

```
s                    AB CD EF GH IJ LM NO PQ RS TU VW XY ZΓ ΔΠ ΦΨ ДЖ
l = s & 0xAAAAAAAA = A0 C0 E0 G0 I0 L0 N0 P0 R0 T0 V0 X0 Z0 Δ0 Φ0 Д0
r = s & 0x55555555 = 0B 0D 0F 0H 0J 0M 0O 0Q 0S 0U 0W 0Y 0Γ 0Π 0Ψ 0Ж
```

Then align the bits of `l` and `r`.

```
(l >>> 1)          = 0A 0C 0E 0G 0I 0L 0N 0P 0R 0T 0V 0X 0Z 0Δ 0Φ 0Д
r                  = 0B 0D 0F 0H 0J 0M 0O 0Q 0S 0U 0W 0Y 0Γ 0Π 0Ψ 0Ж
```

Finally, use `&` to get a `1`-bit if and only if the state was `0b11`.

```
(l >>> 1) & r      = 0? 0? 0? 0? 0? 0? 0? 0? 0? 0? 0? 0? 0? 0? 0? 0?
```

Here `?` is `1` if the corresponding state was `0b11` and `0` otherwise.
The same result can be achived by the simplified formula `(s >>> 1) & s & 0x55555555`.

## Bit-Counting

To count the `0b11` states in `s` we only have to count the `1`-bits in
`(s >>> 1) & s & 0x55555555`.

Bit-counting can be done without a loop as explained in the book [Hacker's Delight, chapter 5](https://doc.lagout.org/security/Hackers%20Delight.pdf) or in this [Stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3815253/6770384).

The methods shown here only apply to a single array element. To count the states in your whole array loop over its elements.

## Optimization

As pointed out by Lundin in the comments, the operation `(s >>> 1)` might me expensive if your processors cannot fit `uint32_t` into its registers. In this case it would be sensible to declare your array `states[]` not as `uint32_t` but whatever works best on your processor – the procedure stays the same, you only have to use more or less `555…`. If, for some reason you cannot change the type of your array, you can still access it as if it had another type, see [how to cast an int array to a byte array in C](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9345555/6770384).

Comment: This will be very ineffective on low end CPUs < 32 bits. It isn't possible to suggest to optimal algorithm without a specific target in mind.

Comment: I think it is effective (no matter how fast/slow it is). Regarding efficiency: I guess even on such CPUs this approach would still be faster than a loop, so it cannot be that bad. Anyways, thinking about stuff like that right now seems like premature optimization to me – OP asked for something "*to avoid [...] compare 0b11 every 2bit*" and here it is.

Comment: Shifting a 32 bit integer on a 8 bit MCU is some ~100 times slower than iterating over a byte array. It is not premature optimization, it is the opposite: real-world optimization.

Comment: `~100 times slower` – Ok, I didn't expect that as that means the shift `>>> 1` implemented in software (by shifting and combining single bytes) would be a lot faster than the hardware shift. I added some pointers to this answer. Thank you for the comments.

Comment: @Socowi Better start with the naïve method `if ((arr[idx] & 0x03) == 0x03) count++;` (same for 0x0c, 0x30, 0xc0) in a loop. Any decent compiler will see dat `arr[idx]`  is used four times, and wil keep it in a register in the loop body. (same for the pointer version). Also, the loop will only need at most three variables, which can all be kept in registers.

Comment: @joop Feel free to add this as an additional answer in which you explain that OP's requirement "*"to avoid [...] compare 0b11 every 2bit"*" isn't useful.

Comment: Thanks for @Socowi  and Ludin and other guys for helping me. 
also, I am sorry for give you not enough information about I'm using 32bit CPU...
If I do onboard test, I'll record the result against the greedy algorithm